# Does Fermat hold in non-standard models?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

Let $n \geq 3$ be a natural number and $PA$ denote Peano arithmetic. Do we have

$PA \models \forall x,y,z \geq 1 : x^n + y^n \neq z^n$?

In other words, does Fermat's Last Theorem hold also in non-standard models of the natural numbers?

If this problem is open, what is its current state of progress?

Comment: I think this is still an open problem. I heard that Angus Macintyre has a draft proof of FLT in PA, but I don't know the current status of the draft.

Comment: There is relevent discussion at  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35746/inaccessible-cardinals-and-andrew-wiless-proof on what Wiles' proof uses.

Comment: @Joel: Yes I saw this discussion, but I think it touches only the subject of inaccessible cardinals, and justufies the proof in $\mathbb{N}$. But of course, I have no idea about the details of Wiles' proof.

Comment: Some related thing: <<To my mind, the highlight of this period of building recursive models for the purposes of independence results was the results of the early 1960s by Shepherdson, who, using algebraic methods, produced beautiful nonstandard models of quantifier-free arithmetic in which he showed number theoretic results such as the infinitude of primes and Fermat's Last Theorem (in fact, for exponent 3) are false.>> The quote is from Kaye's paper "Tennenbaum's theorem for models of arithmetic". – Sergei Tropanets 0 secs ago 


Comment: Is there any news about Macintyre's proof?

Comment: @Martin, "justifies proof in N" doesn't make sense, N is not a theory. In any case, as far as I know, there are people who think that FLT is provable in PA and trying to show that the prove goes can be formalized in PA, and no one has come up with a model of PA that would not satisfy FLT.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to whether FLT is provable in PA or not.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293005/65915)